# Accessing the DOM between two renderers in Electron

Tags: electron, nw.js

Is it possible to do this in Electron:

I want to duplicate a video to a 2nd screen.
This is easyly done, by invoking the following 50 times/second:

```
canvas_context_2nd_screen.drawImage(video_1st_screen,0,0,width_canvas_2nd,height_canvas_2nd);
```

but in electron i have to communicate via IPC...
any ideas? is it possible in nw.js?

Comment: OK, i made it with nw.js. Their Window Object has full DOM access through Window.window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported in NW.js. As DOM windows are in the same renderer process by default, and the Node.js context is shared between them:

http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/JavaScript%20Contexts%20in%20NW.js/

This can be changed to be separate though.